# Fazer overload de operador "<<" separando a declaração(.h) da definição(.cpp)

Tags: c++, template, sobrecarga

Estou tentando separar a definição da implementação de classe em arquivos separados, porém estou obtendo  *undefined reference* no operador *<<*.

O que eu ja tentei:

Alterar a ordem dos objetos na hora de linkar:
só gera mais um *undefined reference* no construtor da classe

Mover a definição para o mesmo arquivo onde está o *main*::
compila, linka e executa sem problemas

o Makefile executa o seguinte:

```
g++ -c -I. -std=gnu++0x -Wfatal-errors log.cpp
g++ -c -I. -std=gnu++0x -Wfatal-errors main.cpp
g++ -o main.app log.o main.o
```

arquivo log.h:

```
class _LOG
{
public:
    _LOG(int level,std::string file,int line);

    template<typename T> 
    _LOG& operator<<(T t);

    static int last_log;
    static std::ostream * out;
};
```

arquivo log.cpp:

```
_LOG::_LOG(int level,std::string file,int line){
    // implementacao do construtor omitido
}

template<typename T>
_LOG& _LOG::operator<<(T t)
{
    *out << t;
    return *this;
}
```

O resultado final obtido quando coloco a implementação no main é que posso usar da seguinte forma após uso de uma macro:

```
#define LOG_INFO _LOG(LOG_I,__FILE__,__LINE__)
LOG_INFO  << "Bla bla bla" << " outro bla";
```

ps: este código é meramente para estudos (hobby)

Comment: Esse é todo arquivo? Não tem `#include`? Curiosamente sem o arquivo `main.cpp` complica um pouquinho, o erro pode estar nele também.

Comment: @bigown desculpe por omitir esses trechos de codigo, tentarei ser mais claro na proxima pergunta, eu não coloquei pois pensei estar implicito quando disse que mudar a ordem dos objetos gerava erro no construtor, logo o #include deveria estar correto.

Comment: Não é uma boa prática utilizar identificadores iniciadores por '_' e letra maiúscula (por exemplo: _LOG) pois esses identificadores são reservados pela linguagem e pela biblioteca padrão.

Comment: O engraçado é que tudo em letra maiúscula é exatamente o que eu odeio na WIN_API, fica tudo com cara de macro, e acabei fazendo aqui

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você recebe este erro de linkagem porque sua função é uma função template.

Funções template devem ter sua implementação declarada na mesma unidade de compilação onde elas são utilizadas, é uma limitação da linguagem. Por isso funciona de você coloca a implementação no main.

O que se faz, em geral, é implementar essas funções diretamente no arquivo .h onde são declaradas, seja dentro ou fora de uma classe. Desta forma todas as unidades de compilação (arquivos cpp) que incluírem sua classe terão acesso à implementação do template.

Isto é necessário pela forma como templates são implementados. Cada vez que se chama uma função template com tipos diferentes é como se o compilador criasse pra você uma nova versão daquela função com aqueles tipos. Essas versões da função vão ser linkadas no executável final. No seu caso, na unidade de compilação que apenas incluiu a declaração da função template, mas sem a implementação dela, o compilador nunca teve a oportunidade de instanciar o template, porque ele tinha apenas a declaração.

Isso pode ser problemático às vezes, principalmente por expor detalhes de implementação em um arquivo de cabeçalho. Em alguns casos isso pode ser resolvido dividindo-se a função template em partes, fazendo com que ela chame funções não-template com o código que não se deseja expor.
Também é um dos grandes culpados pelo tempo de compilação em C++ ser tão alto.

É possível que sejam geradas várias cópias da implementação da função para os mesmos tipos em unidades de compilação diferentes, mas o linker depois consegue resolver isso e apenas uma (para cada conjunto de tipos) é adicionada ao executável final.

Comment: @c-e-gesser Primeiramente obrigado.  
A gente sempre vê por ai que não se coloca implementação nos arquivos de cabeçalho, fazer isso não vai criar varias copias da implementação, uma em cada arquivo onde for usada, gerando um binário inchado?
Mais uma vez sou surpreendido com algo contraintuitivo na linguagem ^^

Comment: C++ é um bicho complicado às vezes, hehe. Eu adicionei mais um parágrafo à resposta, pra tentar deixar mais claro o porque de se ter de fazer assim com templates.